# My Own Nameserver Alias

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm hosting a few clients' websites on a Media Temple VPS, but I'm thinking of moving to another provider.  When I originally set up their sites I had each client point their domain names to MT's nameservers.  So now, if I switch, I'll have to contact them and get them to point their domains somewhere else.

My question is whether I could have avoided this by setting up a CNAME record for one of my domains (like ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com) and pointed those to MT's name servers.  So that if I decided to switch I could just make a change on my end and not have to bother them?  Will something like that work? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but would require to lookup the ip of the CNAME record, 
in some cases you can directly use an A record which points to the correct ip.

Comment: Great. Let me see if I understand this. All I have to do is lookup the ip of media temple's nameservers, then create an A record for ns1.mydomain.com and point it to that ip.  Then when I need to change it, I simply change the ip on that A record to the ip of the new nameserver?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a full solution as you still need the registrar to setup the actual glue records for the domain

Comment: I'm not sure what a glue record is.  Is the process I described above correct? Or am I missing something.  Thanks.

Comment: Even if you had used CNAME's you still need to change the records in the registry if you change the name servers ip addresses.